# Service discovery for microservices

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices, service-discovery

I need some help in understanding how we implement service discovery for microservices in kubernetes.

Im going through some tutorials on spring boot and noticed that wr need to use Eureka discovery for implementing service discovery for maintaining communication b/w microservices. But my question is if we deploy those spring boot microservices in kubernetes, do we still need to use Eureka tool? We can use kubernetes services for implementing service discovery and load balancing right?

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes orchestration platform provides [CoreDNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/coredns/) for Service discovery.  Micro services when they get deployed to the platform can utilise the services by default no need to implement it unless if there is specific requirements which is not satisfied .  Kubernetes [Loadbalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) services type can be used for load balancing of services